# loading mapping table as an entity in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, mapping

This is the latest entity framework with a code-first approach. 
One customer can have multiple properties:

```
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomerToPropertyMapping> PropertyIds { get; set; }
}   

[Table("CustomerToProperty")]
public class CustomerToPropertyMapping
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
}
```

When I load the data, everything works fine. When I try to save a customer, I get

> An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key
>   properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will
>   return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source
>   of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made
>   easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See
>   the InnerException for details.

The same happends even if I have

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
CustomerId
```

in the CustomerToPropertyMapping class.

What is the correct way to retrieve the mappings and NOT the object it maps to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping

```
[Key, Column(Order = 0)]
CustomerId
```

in `CustomerToPropertyMapping` and changing

```
public virtual List<CustomerToPropertyMapping> PropertyIds { get; set; }
```

to

```
[ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
public virtual List<CustomerToPropertyMapping> PropertyIds { get; set; }
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should set primary key in customer Class

```
[Table("CUstomerTable")]
public class Customer
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual List<CustomerToPropertyMapping> PropertyIds { get; set; }
}   

[Table("CustomerToProperty")]
public class CustomerToPropertyMapping
{
    [Key]
    public int PropertyId { get; set; }
    [Column("Customer_ID")]
    public long CustomerId{ get; set; }
      [ForeignKey("CustomerId")]
    public Customer Customer{ get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: my bad, it was missing from my example code (just fixed it). actually I have it added.